# web scraping data with drop_down menu and clicking a button which fetch a table on display

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am totally new to web scraping, never used it, right now i am working on crop yield analysis for that i need to get data of climate information which is available on this site https://www.indiawaterportal.org/met_data/ which needs to select some option from drop down menu and then click buttons shown on the page, which will fetch a table and a graph on display, i can download that table as in csv or excel format, but i want all the data which is a huge amount and i can not do that by my self manually for each state and each data type, is there any way to get all the information in multiple CSV file(one CSV file for one data type for given interval of time)

Comment: please, be more clear in what you are trying to get as an output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the `<select>` (State, District,etc) contains list of values. Once the user has made his selection the URL to the csv is composed.

Example:

```
https://www.indiawaterportal.org/met_data/data/csv/18/8/1/1901/1903/annual_totals
```

- 18    : the state code
- 8     : the district code
- 1     : the data type
- 1901  : from
- 1903  : to
- annual_totals : what to show

All you have to do is to 'scrape' the data of the `<select>` and compose all possible urls based on `<option>` values.

Note that the district `<select>` is built on the fly based on the state selection. 
Example:

```
https://www.indiawaterportal.org/met_data/index.php?/data/state/22
```

should return the districts of state '22'